# running 32 bit jvm alongside 64 bit jvm in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, dns, jvm

I am trying to create a connection to a 32 bit Microsoft access 2010 database using Java and 64 bit eclipse eclipse in windows 7.

I created a 32 bit system dns by reading [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-access/64-bit-driver-for-dsn-for-ms-access-database/be8c0ad4-d8fd-48e0-9026-b95d84135820).  The program to create the 32 bit dns is located at:

```
c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

In an attempt to configure eclipse to run the java class as 32-bit, I selected Run as... Run Configurations --> (Arguments tab)  and entered -d32 in the VM Arguments box, then clicked run.  However, trying to run the program resulted in a dialog box saying:

```
"Could not create the java virtual machine"
```

Here is the code for the class I am using to test a connection to the system dns:

```
public class SoftwareDeveloper {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MYDSNCONNECTION");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable");
            while(rest.next()){
                System.out.println(rest.getString(1));
                System.out.println(rest.getString(2));
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){cnfe.printStackTrace();}
        catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

I am guessing this means I created a 32 bit system dns successfully, but that eclipse is not able to find a 32 bit jdk.  I want to keep using 64 bit jdk with eclipse, but is there some way to configure eclipse so that it can switch from a default 64 bit jdk to a 32 bit jdk when -d32 is given in the run configurations?  Or is there another solution?

NOTE: Installing 64 bit version of MS Access or deleting Access and downloading an Access database engine from Microsoft are not options for unrelated reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download and install a 32-bit JRE (or JDK) on your system.

Find your Launch Configuration (Run As-> Run Configurations...) under Java Application branch.

Go to the JRE tab and select Alternate JRE. Click on Installed JREs... button, add your 32-bit JRE and select it.

Comment: Windows x86 is 32 bit. Windows x64 is 64 bit. But if you just want to run it, you don't need a full JDK, just a JRE will suffice. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

Comment: There's sometimes confusion between `Window -> Preferences -> select appropriate JRE` and `Run As -> Run Configurations...` (the method you described). 

Tip: Changing the JRE through `Window...` sets the JRE for *newly* created projects. Changing the JRE through `Run As...` immediately changes the JRE for the current project.